# Scoring combinations of large amount of Variables in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

I am having an issue with trying to assign a value to a range of combinations of variables.

The code I am writing right now looks like this:

```
if ai_hr_tat_flag = "Y" and ai_hr_flag = "N" and ai_wtp_flag = "N" and ai_prof_flag = "N" 
    then score= "4" ; 
else ai_hr_tat_flag = "Y" and ai_hr_flag = "Y" and ai_wtp_flag = "N" and ai_prof_flag = "N" 
    then score = "4" ; 
else ai_hr_tat_flag = "N" and ai_hr_flag = "Y" and ai_wtp_flag = "Y" and ai_prof_flag = "N" 
    then score = "4" ; 
else ai_hr_tat_flag = "" and ai_hr_flag = "Y" and ai_wtp_flag = "N" and ai_prof_flag = "Y" 
    then score = "5" ;
```

The code definitely works but the issue I am facing is that there are actually 10 variables and I have to code every single combination and give them all scores. Again, not a problem to code but its not efficient and its hard to tell if you miss a combination.
I was looking into using arrays but lets just say that arrays sort of terrify me. 
If anyone can offer any help as to how to attain a neat and efficient solution I would be extremely grateful.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard is right. A lookup table is the clear solution. If, for some reason, you insist on having those scores hard-coded and look for syntax that is easier to read, you can use a `select` statement.

```
data have;
do ai_hr_tat_flag = 'Y','N',' ';
    do ai_hr_flag = 'Y','N',' ';
        do ai_wtp_flag = 'Y','N',' ';
            do ai_prof_flag = 'Y','N',' ';
                output;
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
run;

data want;
set have;
select (ai_hr_tat_flag || ai_hr_flag || ai_wtp_flag || ai_prof_flag);
    when ('YNNN') score = '4';
    when ('YYNN') score = '4';
    when ('NYYN') score = '4';
    when (' YNY') score = '5';
    otherwise; /*this allows you checking if all combinations have been found. E.g. otherwise abort; terminates execution if a combination is missing*/
end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Richard and Petr for your answers, they both worked amazingly well. I really appreciate your help on this.  I am going to keep both versions in my code as they can be utilized for other things too :) Thank you again

Comment: `when ('YNNN', 'YYNN','NYYN') score = '4';` is an  easier way to do that I think.

Answer (score 1):

With such a large scoring requirement you are far better off creating a lookup table of existent combinations and adding a score column than hardcoding if statements.

With 10 3-valued (Y/N/Blank) variables you have 3**10 (or 59,049) combinations to contend with.  I wouldn't want to code that!

Step 1. Get actual combinations

```
proc sql;
  create table score_lookup_table as
  select 
    ai_hr_tat_flag
  , ai_hr_falg
  , ai_wtp_flag
  , ai_prof_flag
  , ... the six other flags ...
  , count(*) as combination_count
  , 0 as score
  from have
  group by
  ai_hr_tat_flag
  , ai_hr_falg
  , ai_wtp_flag
  , ai_prof_flag
  , ... the six other flags ...
  ;
```

Step 2. Edit the score_lookup_table

Enter a score value for each row in the lookup table.  You can use a SAS table editor (view table).  If you are doing lots of copying and pasting export to Excel and re-import when done.

Step 3. Use the lookup table

```
proc sort data=have out=want; by ...10 flag variables...;
proc sort data=score_lookup_table; by ...10 flag variables...;
data want;
  merge want score_lookup_table;
  by ...10 flag variables...;
run;
```

Step 4.

Check `want` for missing scores.  Those will be new combinations since last time you updated the score lookup.

If the scoring mechanism is rule-based there may be an scoring algorithm that could be used instead.